# Call java class method from jar (not main)

Tags: java, jar

Is this possible to call a specific method (other than main) of a class in a jar file from command line?

Comment: You question is very unclear. Please provide more details. The short answer is 'yes'. you can call from the jar everything you can call from main. :)

Comment: You mean you want to run a jar file but invoke a method other than main?

Comment: Yeah, invoke class method from jar other than main using command-line

Comment: Your question is not just unclear but meaningless. You call methods from other methods, not from JAR files. The only method you don't call from another method is `main()`, that being what it's for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are talking about running Java code from the command-line, then no.

You can specify a class name, but not which method to call, that always has to be `public static void main(String[] argv)`.

What you could do is write a helper class (or script like BeanShell) to do that.

```
java -cp theJar.jar;.  my.helper.WrapperClass theClassToCall theMethodtoCall arg1 arg2
```

Answer (score 4):

Put the `Jar` into you class path, instansiate the `class` in question & call the `method`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all you need to do is to create a class (with a main) which calls the method you want.  It doesn't have to be in the jar. It can be a plain `.class` file provided it and the jar are in the class path.

Answer (score -1):

No. It's possible to call class(==main method) only.