# How can I execute a java function from php?

Tags: java, php, exec

I have been given a .jar with the below structure to use in php

```
public class encryption
{
    public static cryptio encrypt(String user, String password)
    {
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    public static cryptio decrypt(String data)
    {
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

I am then able to use the following code in php to access the jar

```
<?php echo exec("java -jar encryption.jar 2>&1", $output); ?>
```

However this currently outputs 'no main manifest attribute, in encryption.jar' how am I able to specify to use the encrypt and decrypt functions from php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [can't call a non-main method from a JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880037/call-java-class-method-from-jar-not-main) file. When you receive the message you're seeing, it means that the JAR [hasn't been constructed properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute) as a main class must be declared. I would suggest creating a wrapper JAR as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11880107/79450).